# C# MVC Dictionary From HTML Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I want to receive a post data from Form to be in this format,

```
public Dictionary<int, int[]> MarketType { get; set; }
```

In HTML form I tried,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MarketType[3][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="MarketType[3][]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="MarketType[7][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="MarketType[7][]" value="2">
```

Assume all checkboxes are checked.

Doing this I'm getting an error,

```
[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   System.Web.Mvc.CollectionHelpers.ReplaceDictionaryImpl(IDictionary`2 dictionary, IEnumerable`1 newContents) +194
```

My question is, is this achievable? How?

If no, is there alternative to achieve something similar?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In your case `name="[0].Key" value="3"`, `name="[0].Value" value="1"`, `name="[0].Value" value="2"`, `name="[1].Key" value="7"`, ....etc. But use a view model so that your can strongly bind to it.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, I want to achieve really is if I'm able to receive the "value" in array, hint `Dictionary<int, int[]>`,  I will try it out.

Comment: Yes, as per the dupe (and my previous comment), but you really should be using a view model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @StephenMuecke, I'm really pretty new to this stuff, I will consider using ViewModel. Thanks for the help.